# Parse multiple named command line parameters

Tags: vb.net, command-line

I need to add the ability to a program to accept multiple named parameters when opening the program via the command line. i.e.

```
program.exe /param1=value /param2=value
```

and then be able to utilize these parameters as variables in the program. I have found a couple of ways to accomplish pieces of this, but can't seem to figure out how to put it all together.

I have been able to pass one named parameter and recover it using the code below, and while I could duplicate it for every possible named parameter, I know that can't be the preffered way to do this.

```
    Dim inputArgument As String = "/input="
    Dim inputName As String = ""

    For Each s As String In My.Application.CommandLineArgs
        If s.ToLower.StartsWith(inputArgument) Then
            inputName = s.Remove(0, inputArgument.Length)
        End If
    Next
```

Alternatively, I can get multiple unnamed parameters from the command line using

```
My.Application.CommandLineArgs
```

But this requires that the parameters all be passed in the same order/format each time. I need to be able to pass a random subset of parameters each time.

Ultimately, what I would like to be able to do, is separate each argument and value, and load it into a multidimentional array for later use. I know that I could find a way to do this by separating the string at the "=" and stripping the "/", but as I am somewhat new to this, I wanted to see if there was a "preffered" way for dealing with multiple named parameters?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My preference for handling this would be to use an existing library, such as the [Command Line Parser Library](http://commandline.codeplex.com/).  (However, by default, it uses a [different input format](http://commandline.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Input%20Specification&referringTitle=Home), based around `--input=Value` instead of `/input=value`.)

This gives you the advantage of not having to write the code yourself, getting a lot of flexibility and robustness, and simplifying your code.

Comment: that is exactly what i was looking for. And I really don't care what input format is used... I haven't distributed anything yet. Thanks for the quick help.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a small function to do what you wanted to do.  It allows you to store all parameters in name-value pairs in a structure.

```
Module Module1
Private Structure NameCommandLineStuct
    Dim Name As String
    Dim Value As String
End Structure
Private CommandLineArgs As New List(Of NameCommandLineStuct)

Sub Main()
    If ParseCommandLine() Then
        For Each commandItem As NameCommandLineStuct In CommandLineArgs
            Select Case commandItem.Name.ToLower
                Case "one"
                    Console.Write(String.Format("key one is {0}", commandItem.Value))
                Case "two"
                    Console.Write(String.Format("key two is {0}", commandItem.Value))
            End Select
        Next
    End If
End Sub
Function ParseCommandLine() As Boolean
    'step one, Do we have a command line?
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(Command) Then
        'give up if we don't
        Return False
    End If

    'does the command line have at least one named parameter?
    If Not Command.Contains("/") Then
        'give up if we don't
        Return False
    End If
    'Split the command line on our slashes.  
    Dim Params As String() = Split(Command, "/")

    'Iterate through the parameters passed
    For Each arg As String In Params
        'only process if the argument is not empty
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(arg) Then
            'and contains an equal 
            If arg.Contains("=") Then

                Dim tmp As NameCommandLineStuct
                'find the equal sign
                Dim idx As Integer = arg.IndexOf("=")
                'if the equal isn't at the end of the string
                If idx < arg.Length - 1 Then
                    'parse the name value pair
                    tmp.Name = arg.Substring(0, idx).Trim()
                    tmp.Value = arg.Substring(idx + 1).Trim()
                    'add it to the list.
                    CommandLineArgs.Add(tmp)
                End If
            End If
        End If

    Next
    Return True
End Function
End Module
```